# How do you locate a YouTuber's next video?

Tags: youtube

Let's say you find [an old video that a YouTube publisher created in 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhm2jU-C1JU). You want to watch the follow up video, so you go to [their upload list](https://www.youtube.com/user/MrMldillman/videos) to find it. But because of YouTube's "infinite scroll" feature and the publisher's large number of uploads, it would take you a very long time to locate the video in the feed (and your browser would probably exhaust your RAM to do it). How can this be done better?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the next in the series was either not made or has been withdrawn from publication. Searching is crude but seems should be enough when either selecting the `PLAYLISTS` version of their upload list (six rows of images, plus one) and finding a promising playlist (click on any one and there are images of the others in the same list in the side panel) or, with slightly greater focus, `SORT BY` "Date added (oldest)", scroll down to `6 years ago` and review those (the 2011 video you found does say the follow up is "next week").

[image: YouTube example]

Comment: Did you scroll to 6 years ago? I scrolled for several minutes and didn't make it to 2 years ago.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky did you sort by old-to-new?